# Windows 8 thinks there's another installation on my other HDD

Tags: windows-8, boot, multi-boot

I have 2 drives, and SSD which is my boot disk and another drive for my data. Data drive only has data and only ever has had data, never has an OS been installed on it.

I installed a new SSD (removed the old one as it died) and install Windows 8 again on my SSD but now when I boot it asks me to "choose an operating system", either Windows 8 Volume 2 or just Windows 8. Volume 2 is what boots to my SSD, the other option is just a boot loop.

Once im in everything is fine and my data drive is there any its all good. But I just want to remove this imaginary Windows 8 from my HDD.

I suspect it might have been caused when I was testing out linux on a spare drive and had to to do things with the MBR and selecting a drive to store the some boot information on? Perhaps its to do with that?

I dont know enough to know what it is thats causing it and so I dont know how to search for a solution. All that ive find is people who have dual boot setups and want to remove the screen. I want to remove the screen but I dont have a dual boot.

In MSCONFIG it shows 2 installations one as C:\Windows and the other as just \Windows. I deleted the second but still the boot selection screen appears.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't format the drive before you reinstalled like you though you did.  The solution is simple modify msconfig and delete the non-working entry

Comment: Sorry Ramhound, but I actually switched to a new SSD, I just wrote formatted as I wasn't thinking. Ill edit that now.

Comment: The solution is the same.  You will need to use msconfig to remove the old installation. Your bootloader wasn't on the drive you thought it was.  Remove the entry by using `bcdedit`.

Comment: I removed it using MSCONFIG but it still prompts. Do I have to use bcdedit also?

Answer (score 2):

you can fix this by using [bcdedit](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2676-bcdedit-how-use.html) in your Windows or [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) software

Comment: Can you explain a bit what im "fixing" as in what is the actual problem. I dont know what I should be doing with bcdedit as I dont really know whats causing it.

Comment: It will help you remove the option with infinite loop so your computer can start without asking you to select an OS.

Answer (score 0):

Go to My Computer properties ( You can Press Windows Key + X and click on System to launch System properties) Go to Advance system properties > Startup and Recovery > Settings and you can select to choose which Operating system you want to open by default and change the time it displays the boot menu during startup.

Comment: But the screen still pops up for a split second and its not fixing the problem of windows thinking there's an installation on my other drive when there isnt one.